# SQL Updating a column to use a max number from another table, but increment by 1 for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table (VersionTEMP) with the following 3 entries:

```
--------------------------------
| VersionName    | VersionID   |
--------------------------------
| a-seattle      |             |
| e-everett      |             |
| k-kitsap       |             |
--------------------------------
```

I need to pull the max VersionID from another table (VersionHistory), then assign that number + 1 to each unique VersionName in VersionTEMP.  So if the max VersionID from VersionHistory is 715, my results would like:

```
--------------------------------
| VersionName    | VersionID   |
--------------------------------
| a-seattle      |     716     |
| e-everett      |     717     |
| k-kitsap       |     718     |
--------------------------------
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: To format: When editing, mark code and click `{}`.

Comment: When you edit your question there is a help button (question mark) at the top of the editor. If you click on that you are taken to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set versionId = 714 + seqnum;
```

If you want to pull the number dynamically:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set versionId = ot.maxversionid + seqnum
    from toupdate cross join
         (select max(versionid) as maxversionid from othertable) ot;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server, quick and dirty:

```
select appname, versionno + 1 from versionhistory where appname = 'Seattle'
UNION ALL
select appname, versionno + 1 from versionhistory where appname = 'Everett'
UNION ALL
select appname, versionno + 1 from versionhistory where appname = 'Kitsap'
GO
```

OR, to get all apps

```
select appname, versionno + 1 from versionhistory order by whatever
```

Can be used with CTE as follows:

```
with CTE as (
    select appname as App, versionno + 1 as VersionNum from versionhistory where appname = 'Seattle'
    UNION ALL
    select appname as App, versionno + 1 as VersionNum from versionhistory where appname = 'Everett'
    UNION ALL
    select appname as App, versionno + 1 as VersionNum from versionhistory where appname = 'Kitsap'
    )
    insert into versionTEMP(appname, versionno) select App, VersionNum from CTE
```

OR

```
with CTE as (
select appname App, versionno + 1 VersionNum from versionhistory order by whatever
        )
        insert into versionTEMP(appname, versionno) select App, VersionNum from CTE
```

CTE isn't necessary though:

```
insert into versionTemp (appname, versionid) select h.appname, h.versionid + 1 from versionhistory h

update versionTemp set appname = h.appname, versionid = h.versionid + 1 from versionhistory h
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon for the quick reply.  Your dynamic answer solved my problem.
I did change some variables around and add a where statement to the bottom, so it looks like this:

```
with [Update] as (
      select [VersionName], row_number() over (order by [VersionName]) as [SeqNum]
      from VersionTEMP Group By [VersionName]
     )
update [VersionTEMP]
    set [VersionID] = [MaxHistoryVersionID].[MaxVersionID] + [SeqNum]
    from [Update] cross join
         (select max(VersionID) as [MaxVersionID] from [OrderHistory]) as [MaxHistoryVersionID]
    where [VersionTemp].[VersionName] = [Update].[VersionName]
```

Thanks again!